# How to keep SQL format when exporting to CSV/Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I would like to export an SQL query result to an Sxcel file (xlsx).
I found a module (https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/6.0.0) to do this, but the xlsx file generated includes some unwanted and non-existant columns such as `RowState`, `ItemArray`, `HasError`, and `Table`.
I used the following command:

```bsh
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Excel -Path "C:\temp\xxxx.xlsx" -AutoSize
```

To avoid that, I exported the query as a CSV file

```bsh
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\xxxx.csv" -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

It don't export these unwanted columns. I load it back using

```bsh
$test = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\xxxx.csv" -Delimiter ';'
```

then I export it to xlsx:

```bsh
$test | Export-Excel -Path "C:\temp\xxxx.xlsx" -AutoSize
```

My Excel file now does not have additional columns.

My problem is that for both CSV and Excel files, the format output is wrong. For example I get `8,0154E+16` instead of `80154026286723600`.
So if I convert the CSV or Excel to an SQL query it results in

```sql
INSERT INTO smting ('iddoss', 'codeexterne') VALUES ('2','8.01540262867236E+16');
```

which is wrong.

How can I keep the initial format from SQL query while exporting to CSV or Excel?

Comment: Change the format of your column in Excel?

Comment: @Larnu I wanted it to be automatic, not manual. So it'd be added in the script code

Comment: You'll need to look at the module documentation of the package you're using then. If it *can* format columns it'll be in it's documentation. If it isn't, it can't, and you'll need to use a different method; such as SSIS (which can export to an existing file, and will therefore use the already set formatting).

Comment: `$DataSet.Tables[0] | Select-Object -Exclude RowState, ItemArray, HasError, Table | Export-Excel ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using `NoNumberConversion` attribute :

```
$test | Export-Excel -Path "C:\temp\xxxx.xlsx" -AutoSize -NoNumberConversion '*'
```